# Apache Drill - Hive Integration: Drill Not listing Tables

Tags: hive, apache-drill

I have been trying to integrate Apache Drill with Hive using Hive Storage Plugin configuration. I configured the storage plugin with all the necessary properties required. On Drill Shell, I can view the Hive Databases using:

```
Show Databases;
```

But when i try to list tables using:

```
Show Tables;
```

I get no results (No List of Tables).

Below are the steps i have followed from Apache Drill documentation and other sources:

1. I created a Drill Distributed Cluster by updating **drill-override.conf** with same cluster id on all nodes along with ZK IP with Port and then invoking drillbit.sh on each node.
2. Started Drill shell using **drill-conf**, Ensured that the Hive metastore service is active as well.

Below is configuration made in Hive Storage Plugin for Drill (from its Web-UI):

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://node02.cluster.com:9083",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql://node02.cluster.com/hive",
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/apps/hive/warehouse",
    "fs.default.name": "hdfs://node01.cluster.com:8020",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

All the properties are set after referring to **hive-site.xml**

So, That's what all others have done to integrate Drill with Hive. Am i missing something here?

Regarding Versions-
Drill: 1.14 ,Hive : 1.2 (Hive Metastore: MySQL)
We also have Hive Server2 on the same nodes, is that causing any issues?
I just want to integrate Drill with Hive 1.2, am i doing it right?
Any pointers will be helpful, have spent nearly 2 days to get it right.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Side note: `ConnectionURL` is useless (or even harmful) since you specific a proper Metastore service URI -- no need to access the underlying MySQL database

Comment: _"when i try to list tables"_ > in which database? If you don't set the implicit DB with `use` command then you are probably defaulting to some dummy Drill-specific area.

Comment: The Drill documentation is quite explicit about `show tables` and `use` https://drill.apache.org/docs/show-tables/

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter As stated above, i can access hive databases in Drill using USE command,(say USE DUMMY_DB), which is also accessible via Hive Shell. After that, In Drill SHOW TABLES is not listing tables.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Ok, i will configure Hive Storage PLugin without ConnectionURL. I will update you if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Drill 1.13 version Drill leverages Hive client 2.3.2 version.
It is recommended to use Hive 2.3 version to avoid unpredictable issues.

Regarding your setup, please remove all `configProps` except `hive.metastore.uris`.
The other configs can be default (it is in [HiveConf.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-1.2.0/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java#L448)) or can be specified in your `hive-site.xml`.

Also in case of empty result after usage `Show Tables;` even after executing `use hive`, check for errors in Drill's log files. If some error is there, you can create the Jira ticket to improve the output from Drill to reflect that issue.

Comment: Thanks Vitalli. I will try connecting Drill with Hive 2.3 with configuration you suggested. I will update you shortly.

Comment: Hi Vitalii Diravka, You were right. I tried out the mentioned configuration on Cloudera Sandbox, and Drill is able to list and query hive tables. Some unknown problem with our Cluster, will ask Admin to look into it. 
To be specific, I just updated the "metastore uri" in Hive storage plugin leaving other properties untouched and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Vitalli, I removed all configProps except the `hive.metastore.uris`. Even after selecting the schema as **hive** show tables command returns nothing

Comment: You can check log file and find out what is the issue to connect to Metastore